# understanding what sounds like 「だけどお値段はもっていません。」

Tags: translation, slang, spoken-language

[西友 CM 盛ってます編](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xOLWkWOrlI)

```
懐中電灯盛り。                       The flashlight style.
角ハンガー盛り。                     The corner hanger style.
延長コード盛り。                     The extension cord style.
ジャポニカ学習帳盛り。               The Japonica study book style.
サンダル盛り。                       The sandal style.
折りたたみ自転車盛り。               The folding bike style.
だけどお値段はもっていません。？？
暮らしのものは安く。西友。           Items for living are cheaper. Seiyu.
```

I'm trying to understand the following phrase at the 10 second mark of this commercial.

だけど...something...はもっていません

It sounds like 
だけどお値段はもっていません。＝ However, we don't have prices??

This doesn't make much sense, though.

What is the original phrase and what does it mean? Also, is it correct to translate 盛り as "style" in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says だけどお値段は盛ってません. 持つ is not relevant, and there is also a difference in accent (盛ってる【LLHH】 vs 持ってる【HHLL】).

[盛る has various meanings](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%8B), but the following is relevant in this ad:

- to top with; to place something as a topping
- to exaggerate; to blow up; to aggressively decorate (hairstyle, selfie, etc)

The latter is a relatively new slang usage. See [this article](https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/fukayomi/ichiran/20160921-OYT8T50141.html) for details. [話を盛る (or simply 盛る)](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A9%B1%E3%82%92%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%8B) is a particularly useful slangy expression.

So 懐中電灯盛り and so on means "topped with ～" (their hairstyle is called [盛り髪](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%8A%E9%AB%AA), so there is another wordplay here). だけどお値段は盛っていません means something like "But the prices aren't blown up". Note that 値段を盛る itself is not really a common set phrase, although everyone can understand it as a humorous expression.